# Axios POST submitting name: field twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I have a very simple POST form in ReactJS. I have two fields in the form `name` and `description`. The form submits, but my issue is that it submits the value of the description into both the name and description fields.

```
{data: {…}, status: 201, statusText: "Created"
{id: 9, name: "Testing the desc", description: "Testing the desc", …}
```

my React JS file:
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

```
export default class NewDistillery extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    description: '',
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value, description: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();    
    axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/distilleries.json`, {name: this.state.name, description: this.state.description} )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <h2>Add Distillery</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label className="input-label">
            Name:
            <input className="input" type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <label className="input-label">
            Description:
            <input className="input" type="text-area" name="description" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <button className="button" type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I tried some options with the setState event such as :

```
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value});
    this.setState({ description: event.target.value });
  }
```

But that's obviously made one difference.

I'm very new to React so not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the name and description with the same input value coming from the last input field on submit which is description.

Use the input field name attribute to decide which key to update

Change handleChange to

```
 handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
 }
```

Comment: I should note I'm trying to create an element here so I want to update all values.

You were right. That's solved it. Thanks. I have more fields to add, do I then do `this.setState({ [event.target.name]:, [event.target.snippet]: event.target.value });

Comment: The way the `handleChange` function is set up, it updates state based on what DOM element was changed, and determines what property in the state to change based on the `target.name` value you set. so as long as the `name` property is different for each input using the `onChange` handler, you can use as many inputs as you want with no other code changes.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a different onChange handler for each input, e.g.  `handleSnippetChange = event => {
    this.setState({ snippet: event.target.value});
  }`. Having separate handlers lets you customize individual behavior later, but if they  are expected to have identical behavior, the other approach may be better. Or even a hybrid approach, where a common method is used by distinct `onChange` handlers.

Comment: Is snippet another input field? If so, you leave it the way it is (as long as the input name attribute is 'snippet')
If the answer is correct can you accept it.Gracias!

Comment: @varoons Yep, spotted that after a little while. It's far more simple than I thought! Have it working well now, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You should follow simple approach:

1- All you inputs should have corresponding state variables with the same name, for example, if you have inputs with names: "name", "description", and "snippet", you should have the same state variables with the exact names, "name", "description", and "snippet".

2- You make a unified handleChange() function, and don't mention input names within it, like:

```
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }
```